# Ruby RegEx problem text.gsub[^\W-], '') fails

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to learn RegEx in Ruby, based on what I'm reading in "*The Rails Way*". But, even this simple example has me stumped. I can't tell if it is a typo or not:

```
text.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub([^\W-], '').downcase
```

It seems to me that this would replace all spaces with `-`, then anywhere a string starts with a non letter or number followed by a dash, replace that with ''. But, using irb, it fails first on `^`:

> syntax error, unexpected '^', expecting ']'

If I take out the `^`, it fails again on the W.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>> text = "I love spaces"
=> "I love spaces"
>> text.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/[^\W-]/, '').downcase
=> "--"
```

Missing //

Although this makes a little more sense :-)

```
>> text.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/([^\W-])/, '\1').downcase
=> "i-love-spaces"
```

And this is probably what is meant

```
>> text.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
=> "i-love-spaces"
```

\W means "not a word"
\w means "a word"

The // generate a regexp object

> > /[^\W-]/.class
> >     => Regexp

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: [Add this to your bookmarks](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html). Whenever I need to look up regexes, it's my first stop

Step 2: Let's walk through your code

```
text.gsub(/\s/, "-")
```

You're calling the `gsub` function, and giving it 2 parameters.
The first parameter is `/\s/`, which is ruby for "create a new regexp containing `\s` (the // are like special "" for regexes).
The second parameter is the string `"-"`.

This will therefore replace all whitespace characters with hyphens. So far, so good.

```
.gsub([^\W-], '').downcase
```

Next you call gsub again, passing it 2 parameters. 
The first parameter is `[^\W-]`. Because we didn't quote it in forward-slashes, ruby will literally try run that code. `[]` creates an array, then it tries to put `^\W-` into the array, which is not valid code, so it breaks.
Changing it to `/[^\W-]/` gives us a valid regex.

Looking at the regex, the `[]` says 'match any character in this group. The group contains `\W` (which means non-word character) and `-`, so the regex should match any non-word character, or any hyphen.

As the second thing you pass to gsub is an empty string, it should end up replacing all the non-word characters and hyphens with empty string (thereby stripping them out )

```
.downcase
```

Which just converts the string to lower case.

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the slashes. It should be `/[^\W-]/`

Answer (score 2):

Well, .gsub(/[^\W-]/,'') says replace anything that's a not word nor a - for nothing.

You probably want

```
>> text.gsub(/\s/, "-").gsub(/[^\w-]/, '').downcase
=> "i-love-spaces"
```

Lower case \w (\W is just the opposite)

Answer (score 1):

The slashes are to say that the thing between them is a regular expression, much like quotes say the thing between them is a string.